# What is (void) with () in C

Tags: c, void

I recently found this line of code, but I don't know what the void with () mean.
Can someone help me ?
Thanks

```
(void) myFunc();
```

Comment: You should add more context. What does the rest of the function look like? At least let us know what it returns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(void)` has the form of a cast operation, but casting to `void` (note: not to `void *`) is normally not a useful thing to do.

In this context, though, `(void) myFunc();` means that `myFunc` returns a value, and whoever wrote this line of code wanted to throw that value away and did not want the compiler to complain about this, and/or wanted to make it clear to future readers of the code that they were throwing the value away on purpose.  In the generated code, `(void) myFunc();` has exactly the same effect as `myFunc();` with nothing in front.

Due to historic abuses of this notation, some compilers will warn you about not using the value of certain functions (e.g. `malloc`, `read`, `write`) *even if* you put `(void)` in front of them, so it's less useful than it used to be.

Comment: What's meant by "Due to historic abuses of this notation"?

Comment: @Zircoz There are some C library functions where it's almost always a bug to call them and ignore the return value, but it's relatively common for it to be _inconvenient_ to do something constructive with the return value. So lazy programmers would code e.g. `(void) write(...)` and compiler developers decided to ignore the `(void)` and hit them over the head with "you should have used that value" warnings anyway. If you want to know more about this please ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

`myFunc` probably `returns` something.  Adding `(void)` to the the function call, `(void)myFunc()`, is a way to self-document the code.  It means, "I know `myFunc` `return`s a value, but I don't care what it is."